# The value/s of $a$ will the linear system have a unique, infinite and no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

For which value/s of $a$ will the linear system have a unique, infinite, and no solution?

$\begin{cases} x+y-z=2\\ x+2y+z=3 \\ x+y+(a^2-5)z=a\end{cases}$

Can someone verify my solution? Thank you.

My attempt

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\  
 1 & 2 & 1 & 3  \\
 1 & 1 & a^2-5 & a\\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$

By Gaussian Elimination
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\  
 0 & 1 & 2 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 & a^2-4 & a-2\\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$

The system will have a unique solution if $a^2-4 \neq 0$. So for $a\neq2$ it will have a unique solution.

The system will have infinite number of solutions if $a$ makes the last row all zeroes. So for $a = 2$, it will have an infinite number of solutions.

The system will have no solution if $a$ makes the last column a leading column, in this case there is no choice for $a$.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: Already picked one thanks

Comment: Which one? None of the answers is accepted. To accept the answer, click on the little tickmark on the left side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors I can see. The first is inconsequential, but in the second matrix, in the augmented column and the second row, you have written $-1$ instead of $1$.

More importantly, $a^2 - 4 = 0$ has a second solution: $a = -2$. If you try this particular $a$, then the system has no solutions.

Comment: Thank you I only got the prinicipal root which is 2 and forgotten the negative root which is -2.

Comment: @BBS Don't forget to accept this answer if it is what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes.

---

One, by Gaussian elimination, the rightmost value of the second row should be $1$, not $-1$.

---

Two, you say:

> The system will have a unique solution if $a^2-4 \neq 0$. So for
> $a\neq2$ it will have a unique solution.

This is false. It is possible to have $a^2=4$ even if $a\neq 2$.